# joining 2 files on matching column values using awk

Tags: join, awk

I know there have been similar questions posted but I'm still having a bit of trouble getting the output I want using awk FNR==NR...
I have 2 files as such

```
File 1: 
123|this|is|good
456|this|is|better
...

File 2:
aaa|123
bbb|456
...
```

So I want to join on values from file 2/column2 to file 1/column1 and output file 1 (col 2,3,4) and file 2 (col 1).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk you could do something like

```
awk -F \| 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR == FNR { val[$2] = $1; next } $1 in val { $(NF + 1) = val[$1]; print }' file2 file1
```

`NF` is the number of fields in a record (line by default), so `$NF` is the last field, and `$(NF + 1)` is the field after that. By assigning the saved value from the pass over `file2` to it, a new field is appended to the record before it is printed.

One thing to note: This behaves like an inner join, i.e., only records are printed whose key appears in both files. To make this a right join, you can use

```
awk -F \| 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR == FNR { val[$2] = $1; next } { $(NF + 1) = val[$1]; print }' file2 file1
```

That is, you can drop the `$1 in val` condition on the append-and-print action. If `$1` is not in `val`, `val[$1]` is empty, and an empty field will be appended to the record before printing.

But it's probably better to use `join`:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -t \| file1 file2
```

If you don't want the key field to be part of the output, pipe the output of either of those commands through `cut -d \| -f 2-` to get rid of it, i.e.

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -t \| file1 file2 | cut -d \| -f 2-
```

Comment: You can avoid piping to cut, add the join option: `-o 1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2`

Comment: I like your use of `$(NF+1)`. You can make it more awk-ish by moving the if  expression outside the braces: `$1 in val { $(NF + 1) = val[$1]; print }`

Comment: @glennjackman Oh, that's a good point. I'll stick with `cut` to shave the key field from the output, though; the `-o` option can solve the problem as stated and has its advantages, but I feel that the advantage of the `cut` approach that it works with arbitrary many columns outweighs them here. If performance was stated as a concern, things might be different, though.

Comment: thanks so much! I can't use join (at this step) since the 2 files aren't sorted.  I am curious about the $(NF +1 ) as I am an awk novice - can you enlighten a bit ?

Comment: Caveat by the way: Only lines that have a value in `file2` are printed this way (it behaves like an inner join, essentially). If you want lines that don't have a value in `file2` to be printed with an empty field, use `{ $(NF + 1) = val[$1] }` without the `$1 in val` condition.

Answer (score 1):

If the files have the same number of lines in the same order, then

```
paste -d '|' file1 file2 | cut -d '|' -f 2-5
```

```
this|is|good|aaa
this|is|better|bbb
```

I see in a comment to Wintermute's answer that the files aren't sorted. With bash, process substitutions are handy to sort on the fly:

```
paste -d '|' <(sort -t '|' -k 1,1 file1) <(sort -t '|' -k 2,2 file2) |
cut -d '|' -f 2-5
```

To reiterate: this solution requires a one-to-one correspondence between the files